# $httpbackend delay with $q and $resource

Tags: angularjs, resources, delay, httpbackend

I'm trying to make a delay inside of `$httpBackend` response, and handle it with `$resource` service like this:

```
$httpBackend.whenGET(/\/courses\/\?id=\d+$/).respond(function(method, url) {
    var regexp = /\d+$/;
    var position = url.search(regexp);
    var course = url.slice(position);

    var courseToRet = angular.toJson(getCourse(course));

    var defer = $q.defer();
    $timeout(function() {
        defer.resolve(courseToRet);
    }, 500);

    return [200, defer.promise, {}];

});
```

And my `$resource` looks like this:

```
var resource = $resource('/courses/', null, {
    'update': {method: 'PUT'}
});

function getCourseResource(courseId) {
    return resource.get({id: courseId}).$promise;
}
```

In my controller I'm trying to get the data like this:

```
Course.getCourseResource(self.courseId).then(function (result) {
    console.log(result);
    result.$promise.then(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        data.$promise.then(function(data2) {
            console.log(data2)
        });
    });
})
```

But it seems like it doesn't work. I'm out of ideas. In training purposes I have to do this in that exact way: by using `$q` in `$httpBackend` to make delay and get data by `$resource`. Thank you!

Comment: I've faced that problem when I wanted to test that the loading spinner is visible when page waits for response but it seems that `$httpBackend` waits for promise to be resolved before proceeding. I've ended up with a method in middleware to set up the delay for response in such cases

Comment: @maurycy can you tell us a little more for that "method in middle ware"??